# how to reflect the changes of a inastance of a class on other page

Tags: asp.net

I have one class.I need the same instance of the same class  at two differnt 
pages with  previous values assigend to that instance.?

so how to maintain the value of a instance b/w two pages....

Comment: Two pages, or two requests for the same page?  Your text seems to indicate the former, but your weak use of the language leaves room for doubt, and the answer will be very different depending on which it is.

Comment: two pages.....let me clear..

I have mailmessage class  on my page.I'm attaching some attachments 
to this  on any ohter page now i want the persistence of those attachments on my page....?

Answer (score 0):

Store it in session:

```
// Store
Session["MyInstance"] = myObject;

// Read
MyObject myObject = (MyObject)Session["MyInstance"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 choices:

**1) Add it to the HTTPContext items and do a Server.Transfer to the other pages.**
-great if you are doing some sort of a wizard
-does not work well with ajax at all

**2) Use a session variable**
- quick and dirty
- won't work well in a farm environment
- attachments sound large; could be hard on the system memory

**3) Store in a database of some sort and fetch on subsequent pages.**
- most complicated to develop
- users can come back later and still get their data
- statelessness is better maintained and works well on farms